# Image is taking more space in cache than the original size of it in tvos

Tags: swift, caching, swift2, tvos, alamofireimage

Idk why my image is taking more size in cache memory than the original size. I am using the alamofireImage library for this purpose and my application is for tvOS. Here is my code.

```
let photoCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
        memoryCapacity: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
        preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 60 * 1024 * 1024
    )


Alamofire.request(.GET, request, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    self.imagesArray = JSON["results"] as! NSMutableArray
                    for result in self.imagesArray{

                        self.getNetworkImage(result["url"] as! String, completion: { (UIImage) in

                        })}}}



func getNetworkImage(urlString: String, completion: (UIImage -> Void)) -> (Request) {
        return Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, headers: headers).responseImage { (response) -> Void in
            guard let image = response.result.value else { return }
            completion(image)
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200{
                self.cacheImage(image, urlString: urlString)
                self.cachedImagesOnly.addObject(urlString)
            }
            if self.counter == 4{
               self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
               self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true

                var downloadedImage = UIImage()
                let dicr = self.cachedImagesOnly.firstObject
                 let urlStringFetch = dicr!["url"] as! String
                print("Fetching url: \(urlStringFetch)")

                downloadedImage = self.cachedImage(urlStringFetch)!
                print("Size of image from cache: \(downloadedImage.size)")
                self.ssImage.image = downloadedImage

                })

            }

        }
    }

func cacheImage(image: Image, urlString: String) {

        print("Total Cache memory size: \(self.photoCache.memoryCapacity)")
        self.counter += 1
        let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
        print("Image size before cache : \(jpgImageData?.length)")
        self.cachedImagesOnly.addObject(urlString)
        let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(urlString)")!)
        self.photoCache.addImage(UIImage(data: jpgImageData!)!, forRequest: URLRequest)
        print("Cache memory usage after image cache: \(self.photoCache.memoryUsage)")

    }
```

Log results:

```
Total Cache memory size: 104857600
Image size: (1752.0, 1896.0) and string as identifier: http://image.com/9493.jpg
Image size before cache : Optional(1738247)
Cache memory usage after image cache: 13287168
Total Cache memory size: 104857600
Image size: (2875.0, 3872.0) and string as identifier: http://image.com/5025.jpg
Image size before cache : Optional(7049508)
Cache memory usage after image cache: 57815168
Total Cache memory size: 104857600
Image size: (2394.0, 3866.0) and string as identifier: http://image.com/169215.jpg
Image size before cache : Optional(6049349)
Cache memory usage after image cache: 94835984
Total Cache memory size: 104857600
Image size: (3811.0, 3049.0) and string as identifier: http://image.com/786.jpg
Image size before cache : Optional(2848557)
Cache memory usage after image cache: 46478956
```

So, I read on GitHub they use FIFO when cache-memory is full so except just removing the first object it removes two or three as per the calculation. Moreover, just consider the first log result the image size is 1738247 and IDK what overhead this is adding to it that after cache the usage size becomes 13287168 which almost 13 times more very strange. If anyone been through this problem or can identify my mistake would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't they decompressed in cache?

Comment: Nop, I have tried in the browser, the image size is perfect on both. so there is some problem in cache.

Comment: it feels like you're comparing apples and oranges. The size of a JPEG representation and the amount of memory used by the `UIImage` object in the cache are two completely different things.

Comment: Point ! but why there is a difference in size when i am downloading image from browser and downloading it through app ? can u explain ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a little complicated because there are a lot of moving parts here:

- First, when you get an image from a web service there is the original asset, a `NSData`. In your code snippet, I don't think you're ever seeing this original asset, because you're letting Alamofire convert it to a `UIImage` (see next point) before it's delivered to you. But if you were watching this in a web browser (or some tool like Charles or WireShark), this is the size of the original asset.
- Then you convert that to a `UIImage`, which if the original asset was compressed, may stay compressed until you first use it in a `UIImageView` or the like.

  As soon as you use this `UIImage`, it is uncompressed, usually taking far more memory, usually four bytes per pixel (one byte for red, green, blue and alpha channels, respectively, though there are other formats, too).
- When you later call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, you are now constructing a new `NSData` from the `UIImage`. People often mistakenly think that this is the same as the original asset, but it's not. If you use compression quality of 1.0, this is often much larger than the original asset (though likely smaller than the uncompressed `UIImage`.) And if you use lower compression quality, the size is often more reasonable, but you introduce some JPEG artifacts due to its lossy compression. (PNG compression is lossless, though usually the resulting assets are larger.)

So, the long and the short of it that you're comparing `NSData` representations (particularly JPEGs with `compressionQuality` of 1) to the amount of memory taken by a `UIImage` which is cached, and I would not expect these numbers to match. They're very different things.

Comment: Very well explained @Rob, but i have one question over here. If you've to solve problem like this, like if you've around 15 images and you've to cache them within a memory constraint what would you have done for this?

Comment: First, in many cases, you don't have to mess around with caches at all, and you can enjoy the caching provided by `NSURLCache` (which `NSURLSession` automatically uses behind the scenes). Unfortunately, the caching of `NSURLSession` is somewhat poorly documented (their are weird rules about no item exceeding 5% of the whole cache) and are reliant upon the headers set by your web service.

Comment: In those cases where I've had to implement my own cache, I (a) cache the original asset, not the `UIImage` to avoid uncompressed images being cached; (b) write caching code that caches to memory using `NSCache` (which I set up to observe `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`, to purge itself upon memory pressure) and to persistent storage in `NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory`, basically trying `NSCache` first, and falling back to persistent storage if the `NSCache` failed.

Comment: a little long way to solve the problem but seems very practical. let me give it a try Thanks v much.